# Not able to create new Activity in android studio(NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to create a new activity it says NullPointerException

[image]

It says IDE fatal when I tried look into the error from the event log

[image]

Comment: That definitely looks like IDE bug, did it start to happen after recent update?

Comment: Why does it seem like you are trying to create an activity in your Layout folder?

Answer (score 1):

Oops!! I was doing it wrong
There is no Issue if I create the new Activity this way.

[image: Creating new activity from the project window]

Comment: how is this different from your first attempt?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov he was trying to create on from Layout resource folder, that is why. Already mentioned in comments to the question

Answer (score 1):

You may not have created entry for intent-filter in manifest.If you are creating both java and layout file separately without directly creating a activity.

1. Create a java file say Main.java

use following code :

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedState);
  setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
}
```

and in manifest add after application tag

```
<activity
      android:name=".Main">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

Open the folder bin under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.

Open the file "idea.properties" and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools.

Add "disable.android.first.run=true" as the final line and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have another layout/activity/menu/or other things.
I faced the same issue, it inserts the activity into Manifest but never creates a new file.
Try these things
Try to use another name activity/fragment/...
Delete other unnecessary things/files e.g. from drawable, files created previously in other directories as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this following things...

- Try to Build Your Project.
- Try to Clean your Project.
- If not work then Restart Project/Android Studio.
- If still not work Then try to Add Activity with Right click and Add
  New Java Class.
- And check SDK is proper

and let me know what happens.

Hope this will helps...(: